# Next.js cache getServerSideProps or getStaticPath

Tags: next.js

I have question about next.js.

I have read about Incremental Static Generation which generate HTML file,
But I have a case like below,

**So my question is below behavior possible with next.js?**

Currently for our server side rendering, we use simple node.js.

1. When user visit page `www.sample/home?number=1`
2. Node.js will request data to another server.
3. Once the data received, Nodejs will create
   `const resultHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Home data={data} />)`
4. the string result will be cache into redis
5. next time when user have same query as no.1, we will immediately return resultHTML.

Below is not real code, but roughly like this

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

import App from '../src/App'

const PORT = 8080
const app = express()

const router = express.Router()


app.get('/home', async (req,res) => {
  const number = req.query.number
  
  let resultHTML = checkRedisForNumber(number);
  
  if(!resultHTML){
    const data = await fetch('urlToData');
    resultHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Home data={data} />)
    cacheResultToRedis(number, result); 
    // future user that use same query will be served from redis
    // this way server does not waste cpu power trying to renderToString
  }

  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
  res.send(resultHTML);

})
```

From my understanding, getServerSideProps() will return props,
and step 3 will always be executed.

**Why there is a need to skip step 3?**

1. we expected 1000 - 2000 unique visitor per seconds during high-traffic.
2. Since page for this query is actually already created in step3 and stay the same, we can store it in cache and immediately return to user

Comment: What's the actual question? Your example isn't using Next.js at all. Is your question about how you would handle SSR caching if you were to use Next.js with `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: Sorry not to make it clear. my question, can next.js handle the same behavior like above.